# Pandas drop level of multindex columns keeping the first column of the second level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a column multiindex. The multiindex stores for some variables in the first level, the mean and the standard deviation of that variable in the second level.
An example Dataframe might look like this:

```
    A   B   C                       D                       E
            mean        std         mean        std         mean        std
0   10  1   1.203992    0.042124    42.863710   1.757129    0.339884    0.064432
1   5   5   2.501185    0.022183    113.286523  2.506529    0.376153    0.062222
2   3   2   2.703891    0.401468    129.841139  21.588131   0.413673    0.014375
3   7   3   3.971790    0.289911    200.276278  17.478694   0.590200    0.017151
```

My objective is to drop the second level of the multiindex and only keep the columns for the mean.
The output would look like this:

```
    A   B   C           D           E
0   10  1   1.203992    42.863710   0.339884
1   5   5   2.501185    113.286523  0.376153
2   3   2   2.703891    129.841139  0.413673
3   7   3   3.971790    200.276278  0.590200
```

How do I apoproach this? I tried simply dropping the second level, but this leaves me with two columns for C, D and E with identical names.

One possible approach that I found was to zip the two levels together with a list comprehension and then dropping the unwanted columns:

```
df.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df.columns]
drop_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.endswith('std')]
df.drop(drop_cols, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

However, this seems impractical and also leaves me with columns that I would have to rename properly.
Is there a better way to tell pandas to drop the second level and keep the first columns for every first level column?

EDIT: The reason I want to do this is so I can perform a pivot like this:
`df.pivot(index='A', columns='B', values='C')`where the values for `C` should come from the mean column and not the std column. Maybe there is also a shortcut for this.

Comment: IHMO, it's really impractical to have single-level columns mixed with multi-level column. How do you got them at the first place?

Comment: Using a groupy with an aggregation for mean and std. How would you suggest organizing the data?

Comment: Then don't reset the index of groupby. That way, `A,B` are indexes and separated from the other columns. With that, you can slice the level with `xs`.

Comment: Indeed, I reset the index myself to store the data in an excel file some time ago. From there, I read it back in. But if I made `A` and `B` both an index (so multiindex for the index), I could use `xs`, correct?

Comment: Yes. That's correct `df.xs('mean', axis=1, level=1)` works very well if `A,B` are indexes. Also, you don't need to reset index to save excel. And you could make `A,B` indexes  when reading excel back with `index_col=[0,1]` option.

Comment: Thank you, I worked it out. However, you do actually need to reset the index to save as excel. Pandas explicitly said that saving with multiindex is not currently supported. Maybe I was working with an older implementation of pandas and newer ones are capable of it.